# htacces is not redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, wamp

[image]
I have root file and in root file public => index.php.I created .htaccess in root and wrote this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

to redirect from root to public/index.php but it is not working. localhost is wamp(apache)

Comment: `root file public` ? That could mean anything, please show exact folder structure

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts in your question. Could you please do let us know from which url to which url you want to redirect more clearly, kindly add that info in your question.

Comment: procject(root folder)=>public=>index.php

Comment: .htaccess this file is in project(rootfolder)

Comment: What is the DocumentRoot folder?

Comment: added image of folders

Comment: You `.htaccess` file in in the `code` folder and not the `public` folder. I would guess that the `public` folder is your `DocumentRoot` or at least it probably should be

Comment: I have to move htaccess to public folder?? @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question correctly, could you please try following. This simply checks if `REQUEST_URI` is null then move further to rewriterule to redirect it in backend to index.php file

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php [L]
```

IMHO When you are using `public/$1` in right side of your rewriterule `$1` is empty since it's REQUEST_URI value is NULL because you are hitting base url, so its better to write `/public/index.php` there.

Comment: RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php [L] it is not working

Comment: @yunusdjanov, could you please do let me know what error are you getting?

Comment: The requested resource / was not found on this server.

Comment: @yunusdjanov, could you please check it now once?

Comment: @yunusdjanov, ok I have set rewritebase value also, please check now, make sure you restart apache service and clear your browser cache before checking url please, let me know then.

Comment: `REQUEST_URI` string starts with a leading slash. If you want to match against root dir then the condition pattern should be `^/$` .

Comment: @AmitVerma, Thanks Amit for correcting it, totally missed it, Thank you, cheers and happy  learning.

Comment: github.com/yunusdjanov/htaccess here is the correct link @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @yunusdjanov, Not sure, could you please let us know what error logs what you are seeing in logs?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  [Wed Nov 18 12:40:45.534935 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 25592:tid 740] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3876
[Wed Nov 18 12:40:46.222196 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3876:tid 812] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.